# IntelliJ PMDPlugin custom ruleset

Tags: intellij-idea, pmd

I want to use custom rulesets with the [PMDPlugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1137) in IntelliJ 2016.1 (on Windows).

The Plugin page tells me

> PMD supports custom ruleset file, to configure goto `settings -> PMD` and add the rule set files that are required.

but i can't find any setting to configure the PMDPlugin (I'm using version 1.7.7). In fact when i'm searching for **PMD** the only item listed in the search results of the settings menu is the Plugin itself. And under `Tools -> Run PMD` the Custom Rules are greyed out.

I found on [this](http://fr33kk0mpu73r.blogspot.de/2016/03/pmdplugin-custom-rules.html) page a possible solution but it doesn't worked for me. And if it would i would like to change the rulesets for different projects and i don't want to modify the IDEA rules for each.

Also i found a solution to set PMD as an external tool, but i like how other plugins (e.g. Checkstyle-IDEA) integrate into the IDE.
I also checked the QA-Plug with the PMD extension but there you can just select the settings and don't specify a custom ruleset.

Comment: And also the [Confluence page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/PMDPlugin) of the plugin says *"PMD supports custom ruleset file, where the user can group together or add his own rules. This plugin supports such rule sets. Go to settings -> PMD and add the rule set files that are required. Now menu items will appear under Tools -> PMD -> Custom for the rulesets added and they can be run."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong place. Go to File > Settings > Other Settings > PMD and there should be a + sign like below:

[image]

From there you can add your own custom rulesets (*.XML files).

Comment: It would be great to have this, but unfortunately this settings doesn't appear! Which version of the plugin and the IDE you are using?

Comment: I use IDEA 14.1.6 and PMDPlugin 1.7.7. Which IDEA version do you use?

Comment: As written above 2016.1 under Windows 7

Comment: You are right. I've just installed 2016.1 to test and it does not work as expected. It is probably possible to add it as an external tool but I believe it will be too much hassle. The easiest "solution" I found was simply using QAPlug - PMD and it DOES allow custom rulesets. Just go to Tools > QAPlug > Analyze Code from there select Run With Chosen Profile click on the dots and on the next screen use the plus sign to create a new profile and import the rulesets you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

PMD Plugin Version 1.8
Support Idea 2016.1

Answer (score 0):

As it was touched on by @dambros: The PMD plug within the `QAPlug` plugin is configurable by clicking

> Tools->QAPlug->Analyze Code...->Run with chosen profile

The above answers assume you are using the `PMD` plugin and NOT the `PMDplug` plugin that resides within the `QAplug` suite.